# Parts of image dissapearing/blocked when scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxHoPYFsTuk&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified i followed this tutorial to make this parallax scrolling effect and after adding my own images, it doesnt work, does anyone know how to fix this?

video link: https://youtu.be/I7JoNXxYCSU

tried making a parallax scrolling website but random parts of the image disappeared

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.foreground {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
}

.background,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.title {
  font-size: 7rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;;
}

section {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <img src="https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/oPzai9kdxxVl.png" class="background">
      <img src="https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/OotzTQMkzcbC.png" class="foreground">
      <h1 class="title">Welcome!</h1>
    </header>
    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet pe?</section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure your snippet works? Can you update your code such that the code snippet demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @DanielCheung Note: I added the snippet after the OP just posted HTML/CSS, no other amends have been made

Comment: @DanielCheung i cant add the images

Comment: Can you add example images you can find on the internet?

Comment: @DanielCheung https://pasteboard.co/OotzTQMkzcbC.png   layer 3                 https://pasteboard.co/oPzai9kdxxVl.png layer4

Comment: You should have edited your question to change the images, so they can be seen properly in the code snippet. I have edited your question.

Comment: @DanielCheung ok sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow

Comment: That's alright. I don't see what issue there is with the demo. Can you screenshot the issue, optionally circle the problem in the screenshot and explain what should be the intended result?

Comment: @DanielCheung ok i added the image on the top of the post, so basically the whole thing is the tower and the red part of the tower is missing / is transparent the yellow part is hard to see but its the bottom of the tower and red is the top of tower

Comment: @DanielCheung did you mange to fix it?